# How can I implement a Google API for java?

Tags: java, api

So I want to build an api for google reader, but really do not know where to begin.

Initially, I was trying to build a auto-screening application to pick reading-worthy articles for me from my subscriptions. So I need google reader api. After search a while, I found there is no satisfying one for me. Then I thought it would be fun to create an api for myself and following developers.

For initial development, I need this api to retrieve article list and URLs of them.
Any ideas about how to do this? I will try out suggestions and report later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/  It's in C#, but if you're looking for info on building a library and accessing the service, this should give you a good start.

Comment: This is using ClientLogin rather than OAuth, and isn't a public API.